# In Java, should I use getters or interface tagging for constant properties?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface

Suppose I am modelling different animals in Java. Every animal has some combination of these abilities: walk, swim and fly. For the example, the ability set is constant.

I can store this information as getters that return constants. For example:

```
public class Penguin implements Animal {

    public boolean canWalk() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean canSwim() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean canFly() {
        return false;
    }

    // implementation... 
}
```

The run-time check is then:

```
if (animal.canFly()) {

    // Fly! 
}
```

Or I can use "tagging" interfaces:

```
public class Penguin implements Animal, Flyer, Swimmer {

    // implementation... 
}
```

The run-time check is then:

```
if (animal instanceof Flyer) {

    // Fly! 
}
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marker interfaces are a bit of an anti-pattern in modern Java, required in earlier times because of no way to directly add metadata to a class. The "modern" approach is annotations:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Flyer {
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Swimmer {
}

@Flyer @Swimmer
public class Penguin implements Animal {
}
```

And the runtime check:

```
if(Animal.class.isAnnotationPresent(Flyer.class)) {
    // fly!
}
```

You can use this approach if all you want to know is if an `Animal` has this trait, that is flight and swimming capability is pure metadata.

What are you trying to achieve? I wouldn't call this OOP, because the OOP approach is usually not to query capabilities and execute object-specific conditional logic, it is to use polymorphism.

Comment: You need a parameter to an annotation interface for it to be available at runtime.

Comment: @Dariusz Good catch! Edited.

Comment: It is a common misconception that annotations are a replacement for marker interfaces. _Effective Java Item #37: Use marker interfaces to define types_, specifically points out advantages of marker interfaces over annotations.

Answer (score 2):

Are walk/swim/fly capabilities related to kind or to state ? This is the real difference between class marking (kind) and property (state).

You have to note that once marked a class can't never be "unmarked". All sub-classes will inherit from it. And the same apply for a single instance as it can't dynamically change his type (at least in Java).

Another remark is related to abstraction. Marking requires other APIs to know about your marking types (interface, class or annotations). Whereas some APIs just have to rely on "abstract interface" (ie method name). JavaBean-convention aware APIs are such examples. And integration will be made more easy than coding specific methods to check for class inheritance or annotation presence.

To conclude, static capabilities such as a `Runnable` command can rely on class marking where dynamic ones must rely on state.